# CSS nth-child(odd) vs Javascript performance

Tags: javascript, css

Have any of you tested the performance of using css nth-child(odd) selector vs javascript in the case where you are building a list of x elements and want to style the odd numbered elements?

Something like the following:

css:

```
#some-list li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #f00;
}
```

js:

```
var theList = document.getElementById('some-list'),
    stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    listLen = stuff.length,
    i = 0,
    someContent = '';

while(i < listLen) {
    someContent += '<li>' + stuff[i] + '</li>';
    i += 1;
}

theList.innerHTML = someContent;
```

Versus the performance of something like:

css:

```
#some-list .is-odd {
    color: #f00;
}
```

js:

```
var theList = document.getElementById('some-list'),
    stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    listLen = stuff.length,
    i = 0,
    someContent = '',
    isOdd = ' class="is-odd"';

while(i < listLen) {
    someContent += '<li' + isOdd + '>' + stuff[i] + '</li>';
    isOdd = (isOdd !== '') ? '' : ' class="is-odd"';
    i += 1;
}

theList.innerHTML = someContent;
```

Comment: CSS will most likely win every time, as it doesn't require any changes to the DOM

Comment: This is not an open discussion board. 1 question => 1 useful answer

Comment: @adeneo: Both snippets involve some form of DOM manipulation, though. The only difference is a single conditional assignment. I don't think the comparison given in the question is a fair one.

Comment: CSS will probably win because the browser is written in C or other compiled and fast languages, but JS is slow because it's interpreted and not strong typed. However, since you use JS in both codes, it should be tested.

Comment: @BoltClock - That's true, as long as the elements are created dynamically it probably doesn't matter if a class is added or a CSS selector that targets without a class is used, one might as well add the styles inline too, it wouldn't really matter, as the creation and insertion is what takes time, not the styling.

Answer (score 1):

I have run the test on jsperf! Please have a look at it:

http://jsperf.com/childperformance1

For sample, I have used only 2 child elements under the list. You can add more child elements and try testing them!

Comment: Your jsperf doesn't include the CSS. Of course, the second code, which has additional instructions, is slower.

Comment: I have added the css in the html. I don't think the CSS will make any big impact!

Comment: Yes, the problem is that jsperf doesn't measure the time needed to render elements depending on CSS styles.

Comment: css 3 pseudo-classes tend to be heavy. This question was more for whether the performance of that is a bigger hit with the overall ecosystem of a page vs the example where there is a ternary evaluation with every element in the while loop.